# Что такое code point и в чем отличие от code unit?

Tags: кодировка

Читаю документ с сайта oracle, где дается описание терминологии, связанной с кодировками.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/terminology.html

Вроде бы, терминология вся понятна, но приведенный пример идет вразрез с моим пониманием. Там написано следующее:

> A Unicode code unit is a 16-bit char value. For example, imagine a
>   String that contains the letters "abc" followed by the Deseret LONG I,
>   which is represented with two char values. That string contains four
>   characters, four code points, but five code units.

Почему в примере написано, что в трехбуквенной строке четыре символа `(character)`, четыре `code point` и пять `code unit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "abc" followed by the Deseret LONG I

«Deseret LONG I» - это название символа из стандарта Unicode (см, например, тут http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10428/index.htm) поэтому и 4 символа: «abc»

code point - это примерно то же, что мы привыкли называть символом. Но не совсем. Например, буква «ё» может быть как одним codepoint'ом, так и двумя - буквой «е» и символом "две точки над предыдущей буквой"

code unit - это единицы кодировки. Байт для utf-8, Слово (два байта) для unf-16 или Длинное слово (четыре байта) для utf-32.

По ссылке выше видно, что в utf-16 (используемой в oracle, судя по фразе «A Unicode code unit is a 16-bit char value») codepoint U10428 кодируется двумя codeunit'ами: 0xD801 0xDC28